# How to formaly write this limit

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have this statement:

$$\forall\varepsilon>0: \quad \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow \infty} \lambda[x:x>\alpha, |f(x)|>\varepsilon] \rightarrow 0$$

Where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure.

Is there a definition for this limit, and if so how does It looks like? For example there is a definition for the limit of a real function $g$ when x tends to infinity.

Comment: You are right. I just changed how i wrote the question

Comment: It's the very definition you mention. The expression $\lambda[\cdots]$ is a function of the real variable $\alpha$, and the limit is being taken of that function as the variable $\alpha$ tends to $\infty$.